# Field Values Are Not Getting Saved

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a action function in `<ActionSupport>` that populates the field values depending on the picklist value selected. When I select the option from the picklist the fields gets populate & get save properly.
It's a form of 400 fields, so to save the partially filled form I'm bypassing the javascript validation using `immediate="true"`
But if I enter other details in other input values & try to save the partially filled form, it doesn't give any error & the records gets save, but only the populated value is saved, the other details that I've entered is not getting saved.

Answer (score 1):

as u have used immediate="true" values which you are filling in field will not get posted to server.
In this scenario you have to pass values using apex:param 
or 
Create JSON and then post it to server and then parse the JSON and save the values.

Comment: On populate function I have around 10-15 fields that are getting populated, after that still I have around 300 fields that need to be filled on that vf page as an input, so when I enter input in those fields it doesn't get save.